# Can I do more than one form for the same model class in symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine

Well, imagine that we have a register form of a class Customer and we only ask three fields (name,surname,email) and after, when this user logged first time we want to complete this information.

First, we have in lib/form/doctrine a file called 'CustomerForm.class.php' wich is generated automatic on command line. In this file we 'setup' only 3 fields and validators and if we wanna use we do something like that:

```
$this->form = CustomerForm();
```

Second, we create manual another form named 'CustomerFormStep1.class.php' where we can setup for validate the other fields. But when we do..

```
$this->form = CustomerFormStep1();
```

it returns error: `Fatal error: Class 'CustomerFormStep1'` not found

What is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the form defined as:

```
class CustomerFormStep1 extends sfForm
```

or similar (sfFormDoctrine etc), and named correctly like you say (CustomerFormStep1.class.php) and in lib/form, then Symfony should just pick the definition up fine.  Did you clear the cache after creating and placing it in the right place? (`symfony cc`).

Answer (score 1):

Create the new CustomerFormStep1 class as @richsage instructed. Then, in your actions you can write something like:

```
public function executeLogin(){
 //before login
 $this->form = new CustomerForm();
}

public function executeLoggedIn(){
 $this->form = new CustomerFormStep1();
 //other steps
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you read the [tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_2/Doctrine/en/12#chapter_12_sub_class)? Extending forms is perfectly described in context with reh admin generator and can of course be applied to any case.